# What are these atg.servlet.jsp.ByteContentBuffer entries in my dynamo.log?

Tags: jsp, atg, atg-dynamo

In my ATG dynamo.log I am seeing thousands of entries like:

```
atg.servlet.jsp.ByteContentBuffer@ed62b0(mBlockCount=4, mBlockSize=1024, mCurOffset=0, mOwner=null, mReader=null, mMaxContentSize=-1, , mInInitOrAdd=false, mBookmarkCount=0, [], , mBlocks=[[B@1eab262) dumping bookmarks, cur offset = 0, owner = null
```

What are they and how do I turn them off?  I know it has something to do with the content of the JSP (BodyContent?) but not sure of the purpose of the logging.

Comment: What ATG version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

apparently, there is a piece of code in your project that prints the object of ByteContentBuffer, which it's toString() method returns the output printed in your log.

It would be very useful if you shared the 50 lines where this code is in the middle of.